# Sell drugs (traditional Chinese medicine) inside iOS App, will the App be rejected Apple review team?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, appstore-approval, review

If I sell drugs(traditional Chinese medicine) inside my iOS App, will it rejected by Apple App review team?

I have Googled about this question but I can not find the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about app store policies. These questions should be directed at Apple. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272166/812149) for the relevant Meta discussion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rated appropriately with relevant documents, Apple review approves such Apps. But there are other constraints. 
You need to be a licensed pharmacist in the country which you are going to sell the medicinal drugs via the App.
If your application handles protected health information (PHI) then you need to be HIPAA compliant (or whatever is the respective country equivalent). 
If you do not, then you are subject to potential lawsuits.

It is recommended for you to consult a lawyer who is local in the country in which you are planning to launch the App.